# Probability of selecting $n$ white balls before $m$ black balls from an urn containing $N$ white and $M$ black balls

Tags: probability

I am working on self-test practice problem 4.23 from $\textit{A First Course in Probability}$, 9e by Sheldon Ross.

The problem states that we have an urn containing $N$ white and $M$ black balls, and we select balls from the urn one-at-a-time, without replacement. We want to know the probability that we draw $n$ white balls before we draw $m$ black balls with $n\leq N$, $m\leq M$.

The solution at the end of the chapter points out that we will have drawn $n$ white balls before $m$ black balls if the first $n+m-1$ balls we draw contain $\textbf{at least}$ $n$ white balls. Then, a random variable $X$ which is equal to the number of white balls drawn from the first $n+m-1$ will be hypergeometric and the desired probability will be:
$$
Pr(n \text{ white before } m \text{ black})=Pr(X\geq n)=\sum\limits_{i=n}^{n+m-1}\frac{\binom{N}{i}\binom{M}{n+m-1-i}}{\binom{N+M}{n+m-1}}
$$ 
However, I have an alternate approach and I want to know if it is valid:

Since our goal is to ultimately draw $n$ white balls, and we want this to happen before we have drawn our $m^{th}$ black ball, I propose that the experiment will end with us drawing our $n^{th}$ white ball while having yet to draw more than $m-1$ black balls.

One thing this means is that the final ball we draw is fixed as our $n^{th}$ white ball and I ask how many different ways can this happen. Clearly there is one outcome corresponding to each possible number of black balls drawn, from $0$ to $m-1$. Thus, I propose an alternate summation based on the same type of combinatorial probability argument that he hypergeometric is defined through as:
$$
Pr(n \text{ white before } m \text{ black})=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{m-1}\frac{\binom{N-1}{n-1}\binom{M}{j}}{\binom{M+N}{n+j}}
$$ 
where the first binomial coefficient in the numerator is $N-1$ choose $n-1$ because one of the $N$ white balls is fixed as the last ball we draw, leaving us to select $n-1$ from the remaining $N-1$.

I know I am not presenting a rigorous mathematical proof of the equality of the two summations. At this point I just want to know: Does my approach also make sense? If not, where have I gone wrong in my reasoning?

Thanks.